# Optimize Scala pattern matching for Java enumeration with @switch

Tags: scala, enums, pattern-matching

I have the following problem:
We have a shared scala-java-project (with members who only write java code), therefore we use java enumerations for one purpose.
But now I want to perform pattern matching in scala on this enumeration, and optimize it with @switch, since the java switch actually can use enums.

But the compiler only complains:

```
error: could not emit switch for @switch annotated match
(args.tileType: @switch) match {
```

where tiletype is the field which contains one of the enum values.
How to fix that the code can be optimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use Java.

Scala contains only approximately the minimum necessary to be able to read Java enums.  You can't create or optimizedly use them in Scala at present (through 2.10).

Comment: well, if this is a fact, I will use Java if the performance really becomes critical

Comment: You can create a hash map from enums to functions and do the switch that way if the list gets ridiculously long.  (Assuming that you can arrange it so you don't have to build the map each time.)